# Cant open Youtube embedded video in second activity from tab layout in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Can't open embedded youtube video api in second activity from my tabbed layout.I can go to second activity if it is not about embedding youtube video and alos i had checked that my embed youtube video api code is not wrong.
Note: I use images with nested scrollview in each fragment.

Here is my codes.

For Frag1

```
package   com.example.androidy.ui.main;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

    import com.example.androidy.Activity2;
    import com.example.androidy.R;

    public class Frag1   extends Fragment {


        private ImageView img1;



        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
           img1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image1);

           img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
           });
           return v;}
    }
```

For Activity 2

```
package com.example.androidy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class Activity2 extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Activity2";

    YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;
    Button btnPlay;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener mOnInitializedListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting.");
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mYouTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubePlay);

        mOnInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Done initializing.");
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("smJ2nnVv-DE");

            }
@Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Failed to Initialize.");
            }


        };
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick: Initializing YouTube Player.");
                mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(YouTubeConfig.getApiKey(), mOnInitializedListener);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And Here is my error

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

P.S:Can Someone plz help me solve this problem.

Comment: check if you have btnPlay in your xml of activity2

Comment: @TusharPingale Yes bro I have